# Creating an IntentFilter to match a URL with no scheme or host

Tags: android, textview, android-intent, xamarin.android

I have an activity defined thus:

```
[Activity (Label = "MyActivity")]   
[IntentFilter (new[]{Intent.ActionView},
Categories=new[]{Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable}, 
DataScheme="")] 
public class MyActivity : Activity
{}
```

or for the non-monodroid folk:

```
<activity android:label="MyActivity" android:name="com.myapp.android.MyActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It contains a text view, which I populate with HTML thus:

```
Android.Text.ISpanned spannedContent = Html.FromHtml (someHTML);                     
textView.SetText (spannedContent, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

The links show up as clickable, so far so good. However, the content of my links are like:

```
Here is a link to: <a href="/blah">blah<a>
```

I can't figure out how to match the resulting Intent resolution to my activity. I've tried a few combinations of DataScheme/DataHost/DataPath and with/without Categories. Modifying the url to be like:

```
<a href="customScheme://blah">blah</a>
```

and setting the corresponding scheme in the intent filter DOES work, but I'd prefer not to be in the business of modifying the incoming html.

Any chance of matching that without having to modify the html itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if this were a `WebView`, you'd use `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, to specify where the relative path is relative to. However, I don't see where you can do that with a simple `Html.fromHtml()` call. You could try the `fromHtml()` variant that takes an `Html.TagHandler` as a parameter and have it massage the links into something real.

However, `/blah` won't resolve to anything on Android, so, one way or another, you have to modify the HTML.

Comment: In the end I went with modifying the html to insert a custom scheme. Not what I wanted, but works well enough.